# Show rdlc report in ReportViewer without tableadapter

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I show my rdlc report in the ReportViewer without using tableadapters ? Is it possible ? Please refer me somewhere, or help me on your own. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, certainly it's more than possible, it's straightforward (well, as far as *anything* with RDLC is *ever* straightforward!).

You need to ensure the objects in your program have been defined as data sources (**Data** -> **Add New Data Sources**). If you've done that the data sources will be available to you in the report (**Report** -> **Data Sources ...**). See them listed something like this:

[image]

No DataTables or TableAdapters anywhere to be seen ...

If you need more help please supply more information and tell us what you've tried.